# Problems creating DDL from MySql workbench

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ddl

Is there perhaps anyone who has experience with this problem:

I am trying to export data and create DDL from mysql workbench, using mariadb.

But when I click server > data export, I can see nothing. No errors, no anything.

I'm kind of lost, got an exam coming up on Friday.

Any suggestions are super welcome.

Thanks!

[This is what I see:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1qVa.png)

I tried looking for a fix online, but only found explainations for 'real' errors.

Comment: You must study User Manual for your product before an attempt to do something. [Data Export and Import](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html).

Comment: "mariadb - Warning - not supported"  - could be the reason.